# Sanitizing User Input using Form API - Creating Nodes

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I'm using D7 Form API to make some custom forms for users that create nodes on submit (using node_submit & node_save functions). This is an example form I'm using:

```
function create_article_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['node_title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Node Title'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
 );

$form['submit_button'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Create Node'),
 );

return $form;
}
```

This works great, but I'm just wondering about sanitization. From my research it seems like the check_plain() function should be used for text fields for security. However, it also causes raw HTML entities to be saved.

For example, I am setting the node title in the submit function like this:

```
$node->title = check_plain($form_state['values']['node_title']);
```

This problem is, if the user enters something like this:

```
Mike's Tacos
```

it gets saved in the node title like this:

```
Mike&#39;s Tacos
```

So if I output that title anywhere (in a view, in a custom node--XX.tlp.php, etc, it shows in this way.

Can anyone help with how to still use check_plain (or whatever function will provide the best security) but have the value saved with the human-readable format (Mike's Tacos)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters are used for **output**, not input. It's the Drupal way; save the raw, un-sanitised data in storage, and filter (and cache) when it's being rendered.

You shouldn't run `check_plain()` on your node title before saving it, as it will be run through the same function by core/contrib when the node is being rendered, hence the double-encoding you're probably seeing.

If you're responsible for rendering the node title yourself at any point, you should always run it through `check_plain()` first:

```
echo check_plain($node->title);
```

But always on output, never on input.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up for me, Clive! Marked as answer.